# Alternate Without Semaphores

Tags: linux, c

The program below creates two processes.

The parent process prints the numbers from 0 to 9, while the
child process prints the characters from A to J.

How can I make it alternate the printing using only signals? so no using semaphores or any IPCs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i = 0;
        if (fork() == 0) /* Child process */
        {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        printf("%c\n", i + 65);
                }
        } else /* Parent process */
        {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        printf("%d\n", i);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: for readability, please consistently indent the code.  THe current random indenting is very difficult to read/understand

Comment: you can use thread, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
        int i=0;
        int status;
        int childPID = fork();


        if (childPID == 0) /* Child process */
        {


                for(i=0;i<10;i++){

                     printf("%c\n",i+65);
                     kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
                }


        } else /* Parent process */
        {


                for(i=0;i<10;i++) {


                    waitpid(childPID,&status,WUNTRACED);
                    printf("%d\n",i);
                    kill(childPID, SIGCONT);
                }
        }
}
```